# What is the way to Download or Build a maven project in GCP instance?

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform

I am setting up a new maven project in GCP instance, I have some maven dependecy for apache pulsar.
Ehat is the appropritae solution to create a maven project or Download a dependency in GCP instance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install maven in your GCP instance. As simple as this.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than installing maven in `GCP` instance, downloading dependencies and building an artifact, you should setup build/deployment pipelines in your (company's) infrastructure and deploy the artifact to `GCP` instance.

There might be cases when your app uses some dependencies which are available within your internal network only. This would cause your GCP build to fail and you will then have to setup VPC/VPN between `GCP` and your network which would complicate the network stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google Cloud [Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/). For Building, testing, and deploying artifacts